# ImageView no margin when added to Relative Layout Dynamic

Tags: android, imageview, android-relativelayout, dynamic-programming, margins

I'm having problem when adding the Imageview in my relativelayout if a layoutparams is added to the view, the imageview will not add but if the imageview has no layoutparams, it will show but no image. Imageview is created through code.

```
TableLayout imageCon = (TableLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.home_screen_table_imagecon);
TableRow imageTableRow = new TableRow(root.getContext());
    TableRow.LayoutParams rowSpanLayout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

imageTableRow.addView(getLove());
imageTableRow.addView(getHappy());
imageCon.addView(imageTableRow,rowSpanLayout);
imageCon.setShrinkAllColumns(true);

private ImageView getLove(){
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10,10);
    imgLove.setLayoutParams(lp);
    imgLove.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_emo_love);

    return imgLove;
}
private ImageView getHappy(){
    imgHappy.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_emo_happy);
    return imgHappy;
}
```

I'm looking forward for your help guys.

Thanks
Chkm8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `TableRow.LayoutParams` , since your adding the `ImageView` into a `TableRow`

Change the `LayoutParams` as

```
TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10,10);
imgLove.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

If `ImageView` is added to a `RelativeLayout` then use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`

If `ImageView` is added to a `LinearLayout` then use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

Comment: Thanks, Libin, it works. :) , ill take note of this when using LayoutParams

Answer (score 0):

put below line in xml ImageView tag

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

enjoy...